# Sum two dictionaries with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries which looks like this:

```py
first_dict = {"key": {"key": {"a2": x, "a3": y, "key": {"key": 1, "key": 2}}}}
second_dict = {"key": {"key": {"a2": x, "a3": y, "key": {"key": 3, "key": 4}}}}
```

I want to sum those dictionaries, but leave a2 and a3 keys as the are in the final result, so that finals result will look like this:

```py
result_dict = {"key": {"key": {"a2": x, "a3": y, "key": {"key": 4, "key": 6}}}}
```

I have a recursive way to sum those dictionaries:

```py
def sum_dicts(first_dict, second_dict):
    if isinstance(first_dict, dict):
        return {k: sum_dicts(first_dict[k], second_dict[k]) for k in first_dict}

    return first_dict + second_dict
```

but I have some trouble to understand how to keep those a2 and a3 keys in final result as they are, since I know their values are equal in both dictionaries [and there is no need to verify that]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: why don't you use another dict to keep and update your results ? that would be more convenient.

Comment: What are `x` and `y` and how do you determine that they should not be added? What if the values are different for those keys?

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, z and y they just values, just some numbers, I want to keep those in the final result, exactly as they are but want so sum the rest. I mean I want to sum values of the keys, accept if the key == a2 or key == a3, those I want to take as they are to the final result

Comment: Utils where does it came from ? is a builtin module ? need bo be installed ?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question, no Utills anymore, its just a recursive call

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense, consider `"key": {"key": 1, "key": 2}` => this reduces to `"key": {"key": 2}` anyway -- since the key `key` is re-used, and gets overridden. So how do you expect to acheive the expected output in this case?

Comment: where it is reduses? I need to sum two dictionaries except a1 and a2, its not reduces in any place.

Answer (score 0):

Before you sum the values, you can check that the last seen keys for both have a name that meets a specific criteria:

```
first_dict = {"key": {"key": {"a2": 1, "a3": 2, "key": {"key_1": 1, "key_2": 2}}}}
second_dict = {"key": {"key": {"a2": 1, "a3": 2, "key": {"key_1": 3, "key_2": 4}}}}
def get_sum(d1, d2, name = None):
  if not any([isinstance(d1, dict), isinstance(d2, dict)]):
     return d1 if not name.startswith('key_') else d1 + d2
  return {i:get_sum(d1.get(i, {}), d2.get(i, {}), i) for i in set(d1)|set(d2)}

print(get_sum(first_dict, second_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'key': {'key': {'a3': 2, 'a2': 1, 'key': {'key_1': 4, 'key_2': 6}}}}
```

Comment: thanks for help, already handled that the other way, with the additional dictionary which I update along the way, but thanks, helpful solution